# Как в jsoup изменить value текстового поля и отправить данные?

Tags: jsoup, java

Мне необходимо вбить данные в текстовое поле и нажать на эмулировать нажатие на enter.
Вот мое решение на jsoup:

```
Connection.Response res = Jsoup.connect("http://google.ru")
            .data("q","test")
            .method(Connection.Method.GET)
            .execute();

    Document doc = res.parse();
    System.out.println(doc);
```

Почему нажатия нет данных в текстовом поле, после того как я нажал на кнопку? И нажал ли я на кнопку? Я понимаю, что можно сделать поиск в google иначе, но мне необходимо именно таким образом.

Answer (score 1):

Прежде всего необходимо отойти от образа браузера и понять как на самом деле работает клиент-сервер. Нажатие на кнопку в браузере просто посылает определенный запрос или запускает определенный скрипт и вы видите результат.

Чтобы посмотреть что передается серверу и какой ответ от него можно воспользоваться снифферами и анализаторами пакетов.

Для просмотра запросов и ответов можно воспользоваться встроенный отладчик в браузер или же стороннюю программу. Например [Fiddler2](http://www.telerik.com/fiddler).

В итоге вы должны будете понять какие данные вам необходимо посылать, какой метод запроса использовать и какой ответ от сервера ждать.